# Meaning of the += operator when using a function?

Tags: actionscript-3

If I see something like this:

```
myVariable += myFunction();
```

How does that work? Like, for example, is the myFunction() function supposed to return a value that is added to myVariable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's correct.  `myFunction()` is evaluated first, (e.g., it'll run and return its value), then its return value will be added to myVariable.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on your the result of your function and the value of your existing value that your are adding.

1. If the preceding `myVariable` is a string and the result is a number the values will be concatenated as a string.
2. If the preceding `myVariable` is a number and the result is a number the values will be handled as a sum of numbers.
3. If the preceding `myVariable` is a number or string but the result is a string the `myVariable` will be treated as a string, and the values will be concatenated.

Answer (score 1):

I assume it's the equivalent of

```
myVariable = myVariable + myFunction();
```